# VIRUS like activity of snapd

Tags: 16.04

Hey **notes** are available for snap in ubuntu.
So I tried

```
sudo snap install notes
```

It start to download core package for ubuntu[for snaps i guess] which was around 60MB. Then I said hah i don't need it. So i did **Ctrl+C** to just end it and i close the terminal.

Now my indicator netspeed is constantly showing me DOWN speed. So i ran **nethogs**. It showed ***/usr/lib/snapd*** was downloading and using all my bandwith.

**System monitor** was not showing **snapd** so i couldnot killit from there.

I ran killall snapd without sudo which showed me the PID but couldnot kill it. So

```
sudo killall snapd
```

So after doing all above **indicator netspeed** and **nethogs** both are still showing constant download of some data by **snapd**.

I reboot my laptop and post this here in askubuntu because without rebooting even it won;t load this page as **snapd** was using all bandwith.

P.S I have a 256 Kbps internet speed here.

Updates:
After the reboot...

```
android@android:~$ sudo snap install notes
error: cannot install "notes": snap "ubuntu-core" has changes in progress

android@android:~$ sudo ps_mem | grep snap
  9.0 MiB +  37.0 KiB =   9.0 MiB   snapd
```

System monitor doesnot show the snapd however.

Comment: I don't know about the network usage, but `snapd` is *definitely* not a virus.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to work with snap in future you can remove it by typing:

```
sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools
```

in terminal.